# Proof of the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I need help with proving that:

$(A + BC)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}B(I_m + CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}$

when $I_m + CA^{-1}B$ is invertible.

Comment: Use curly braces `{ }`. Please show some of your working/thoughts, if possible.

Comment: Okay thanks. Unfortunately I haven't come up with any idea yet.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Direct_proof) suggests a direct multiplication. Note $C = I$ in your case.

Comment: You may put $X=B$ and $Y=CA^{-1}$ to reduce the identity to $(I+XY)^{-1}=I-X(I+YX)^{-1}Y$. Then left-multiply both sides by $I+XY$ to finish.